# How to query ssrs dataset

Tags: ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, reportingservices-2005

I want to query ssrs dataset to a get row on the condition.
Say, select * from dataset where column='data'

I tried,

```
Iif(Fields!empname.Value='name',Fields!empcode.value,nothing).
```

Comment: See this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-builder-functions-lookup-function?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: I tried lookup&lookupset but it is not working. It's giving null value. I don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: You'll need to show a small sample of data from the two datasets and show the LOOKUP() expression that is not working.